# NSImageView (added programmatically) doesn't show image, but shows color

Tags: cocoa, swift4

Swift 4. Very simple project, all I did - just added a `NSImageView` programmatically, `backgroundColor` and `NSImage` from the .jpg file. I see the good pink color, but can't see the image at all! I tried many different approaches and some was successful (Image showed up well in collection view and if `NSImageView` was added manually in the story board) but I need in simple programmatically method. Here is all of my code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var image: NSImage = NSImage()
    var ivTest = NSImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.ivTest)
        self.ivTest.wantsLayer = true
        self.ivTest.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemPink.cgColor
        self.ivTest.layer?.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

        let manager = FileManager.default
        var url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        url = url?.appendingPathComponent("night.jpg")
        image = NSImage(byReferencing: url!)
        if (image.isValid == true){
            print("valid")
            print("image size \(image.size.width):\(image.size.height)")
            self.ivTest.image = image
        } else {
            print("not valid")
        }
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

output:
[image]

result:
[image]

thank so much...

--- edited ---

Yes, thank You! Just added this and saw image:

```
self.ivTest.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Comment: What is the frame of `self.ivTest`?

Comment: As Willeke mentioned, your frame is not configured in your code. set frame for ivTest or use autolayout to give ivTest size.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that `layer.frame` and `frame` are different )) , thanks!